# Jquery getScript and eval scripts in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a ajax pages transition and i have this piece of code:

```
if ($(response).filter(".ajaxJs").index() > 0)
{
    $(response).filter(".ajaxJs").each(function () {
        if ($(this).prop("src") != '') {
            $.getScript($(this).prop("src"));
        } else {
            eval($(this).html());
        }
    });
}
```

this script takes care of load Javascript files and Javascript codes to new page.
the problem is that sometimes that i have code and file together in page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/multipleSelect/jquery.min.multipleSelect.js" class="ajaxJs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" class="ajaxJs">
                        if($(".multipleSelect").length > 0) {
                        $('.multipleSelect').SumoSelect({
                            selectAll: true,
                        });
                    }
</script>
```

the code load before the file and throw error SumoSelect function does not exists, because the file not loaded.

How can I sync this that all files loaded before all codes...
thank you

Comment: you can't, other than by first removing them from teh html string before parsing them. :) this is why including javascript in page partials retrieved by ajax is a very bad idea. Your only options are regex htmlstring parsing or normal htmlstring parsing. It has to be done before it's converted to a dom fragment, so jQuery is of no help.

Comment: you can always wrap the code in an inline script in a self-calling/waiting wrapper that looks for a part it needs. `(function wait(){  if(!window.whatever) return setTimeout(wait, 50);  ...  }());` it should still work on the orig page, without waiting as the file above it will be sync-loaded, which is not the case for async injection, but under async, it will self-wait until the time is right to execute. if you have a bunch of these on the same page it can get complicated, but for what's shown, i've used this pattern several times in the past just fine.

Comment: Have you tried moving the problematic code inside the success callback of $.getScript()?

Comment: how i moving the problematic code... i need use each...